# Is asking about the audience issue in blogging on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask this question: **Which donating service should I use for my blog?**

Moreover, I want to have an opinion about my claim makes in [the proposal of Blogging](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21797/110971). I'm sorry that I didn't ask you first :(

I think such questions are on-topic here, based on the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Creating, expanding, and cultivating communities, their content, and the relationships among members. This includes things like attracting new people with advertising, **get more contributions from members**, moderating your moderators, or just making your community grow as a whole.

If *contributing* means money or knowledge, then I think my first question is on-topic. But it's not clear for me that any question about blogging will be good here.

Comment: No `on-topic` tag?

Comment: Use the [meta-tag:scope] tag instead.

Comment: I think we can add `on-topic` as another name of `scope` tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have two (or three) separate questions here.

- **Which donating service should I use for my blog?** - This is a very broad question that is, basically, asking for a [shopping list](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1270/shopping-questions-on-community-building) of possible responses. As phrased, it is off topic. However, I can very easily see a question along these lines being focused and made to be on topic. Donations, advertising, sponsorship, etc. are all relevant to building and sustaining some communities.
- **Is asking about the audience issue in blogging on-topic?** - Blogs are a unique snowflake. There are blogs that form communities around them, but there are others that just want readers. You'd have to explain what you mean by "audience issue". [Improving engagement](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/increasing-engagement-on-a-new-gaming-blog) and [building content](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/464/recruiting-guest-content-creators) for a blog is on topic.
- **If contributing means money or knowledge, then I think my first question is on-topic. But it's not clear for me that any question about blogging will be good here.** - To me, "contributing" means "time, knowledge and/or finances". If the question is about how to improve user contributions and you have a question that is focused enough for us to answer, it is welcome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, should I ask about the donating service?

Comment: @Ooker, if you can phrase the question in such a way that it doesn't read as "recommend a donation service that I should use", yes.

Comment: I have an idea. Instead of asking the question is the blogger's view, how about to ask it in the reader's view?

Comment: Point of view isn't an issue, though it could provide different answers.